# Mock not saving state

Tags: java, testing, mocking, easymock

I'm unit testing with easymock and having a result not set in the answer object. The mock object is passed to the testing subject and after processing the same reference of the mock object is returned, but it doesn't hold the result set to it.

The code should make the picture clearer

```
@Test
public void test() {
DomainInterface mock = EasyMock.create("mock", DomainInterface.class);
Subject subject = new Subject();
subject.setDomainInterface(mock);

final DomainInterface domain = subject.process();

assertEquals("Not the same instance", mock, domain);

final String expected = "VALID";
final String answer = domain.getAnswer();

assertEquals("Not the expected answer", expected, answer);
}
```

What Subject.process is doing is a couple of validations and then setting "VALID" to the answer, but the execution fails with the assertion error message

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Not the expected answer expected:<VALID> but was:<null>
```

The subject object has a private member of type DomainInterface where the mock's reference is set, why would the answer not hold till the assertion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. I suggest you extract enough to make it a short but complete program, and post that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just noticed that you're asserting that the same mock *is* being returned. You're also never calling `replay()` to put the mock into replay mode - if you had, it would throw an exception as soon as `Subject` tried to call any methods on it.

My guess is that you're *expecting* the mock to remember a call to `setAnswer` and reply with the same result when `getAnswer` is called - but mocking doesn't work like that. You should probably *expect* a call to `setAnswer("VALID")`. Something like this:

```
public void test() {
    DomainInterface mock = EasyMock.create("mock", DomainInterface.class);

    // Expect that the subject will call setAnswer with an argument of "VALID"
    mock.setAnswer("VALID");

    EasyMock.replay();

    Subject subject = new Subject();
    subject.setDomainInterface(mock);

    DomainInterface domain = subject.process();    
    assertEquals("Not the same instance", mock, domain);

    // No need to assert the result of calling getAnswer - we've already asserted
    // that setAnswer will be called.
}
```

Personally I'm becoming a fan of hand-written fakes for many tests - mocks are great for *interaction* testing (aka *protocol* testing) but in this situation it looks like a simple fake would do just as well... or possibly a mixture, which fakes out the simple bit (the property) but allows mocks for the bits which require interaction testing.

Comment: Thank you, as you noted I never called the replay() for that mock and misunderstood the way the mock should work. Now it's working.